# Entity Framework Core - Earlier data migrations break when models are changed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We are starting a new application with with .NET Core, EF Core and Postgres - we're really liking the migrations :-)

However, I've found a problem that I can't figure out how to work around. In some of our migrations, we use the `DbContext` to load records, run some business logic, and resave the records. We also run `database.Context.Migrate()` when the web server starts, so it always runs.

This all works fine (so far).

Unfortunately it works right up until the model is changed at a later point. Consider the following migration order:

1. Create `Customer`, `Order`, and `OrderLine` models. Add the schema migrations to load the structures
2. A business rule changes, so we need to set a value on the `Order` record based on some business logic . We create a data migration where we load the `DbContext`, run the code, and run `SaveChangesAsync()`

   At this point, everything is fine.
3. We need to add a schema migration with a new field to the `Customer` record.

Here, things break. If the database has not had migration 2 applied, the `Migrate()` command errors as when applying migration 2, EF is trying to generate a select statement that includes the new field in 3.

I'm not sure where the problem actually is in the process though: should we not be using the `DbContext` in the migration (and hand-code SQL statements)? Should we be explicitly be doing projections on every record read so that we know exactly what we're doing?

Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, 1 and 3 are Schema Migrations and 2 is a Data Migration.

Since Entity Framework Core will generate queries based off the current models in code, and not the current state of the database, there is two options for handling Data Migrations.

1. **Perform Data Migrations In-Order with Schema Migrations**

   Use something like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) or [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples) to perform data migrations based on the schema at the time the migration is written.  You can get the `DbConnection` object from the EF Context using `context.Database.GetDbConnection()`

   *Pros:* Migration code will never need to be changed

   *Cons:* You won't get any of the benefits of EF Core
2. **Perform Data Migrations After Schema Migrations**

   EF performs migrations in the ascending order of the `MigrationAttribute.Id` string value.  EF generates this based off a timestamp when calling `dotnet ef migrations add xxx`.  You can change this attribute to ensure Data Migrations are run after all Schema Migrations.  Change the filename as well for readability so that they stay in the order they will be applied.

   *Pros:* You get all the benefits of EF Core

   *Cons:* If the schema changes in the future, such as removing a column referenced in the data migration, you will need to modify your migration

   Example `MigrationAttribute.Id` change:

```
// change
[Migration("20191002171530_DataMigration")]
// to
[Migration("99999999000001_DataMigration")]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Caleb. For my particular situation, I ended up changing my data migration to use a projection via the `Select` statement, rather than selecting all fields. This avoided the error I'm currently experiencing, but I'll keep your suggestions in mind for future problems.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and landed on this question; I thought I'd share the technique I used to resolve my problem for posterity.

In my case, we had a model `Something` that initially had a field/database column `property`, but the field was deprecated because `property` ended up being stored elsewhere. We wrote a data migration that referenced `Something.property` and moved it to its new location.

We wanted to update the domain model to remove `property` from `Something` as well. However, doing so would break the typechecking in the data migration.

We *must* have a type that has `property` on it to allow the data migration to typecheck. However, we *must not* have `property` on the domain model.

The solution was to introduce `MigrationDbContext`, which subclasses the standard `DbContext`. `MigrationDbContext` exposes a second projection of the `Somethings` table, called `Somethings_WithProperty`. This projection is a `public DbSet<SomethingWithProperty>`. The `SomethingWithProperty` class is a record of the historical type of the model with its contemporary properties; and importantly, we only allow the Type to show up in our `Migrations` folder. `SomethingWithProperty` is stored in `Migrations/HistoricalModels`.

Now, my data migration acquires a `MigrationDbContext` from dependency injection instead of a `DbContext`. I can replace the reference to `dbcontext.Somethings` with `dbcontext.Somethings_WithProperty`, and the data migration can typecheck. My domain model on the other hand will never be procured from the `MigrationDbContext`, so the only `Something`s it can get are from the `Somethings` DbSet, which correctly omits the `property` that we dropped.

A few caveats; if your DbContext constructor takes a generic `DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>` parameter, then to satisfy dependency injection, you will need to introduce a `protected` constructor on `MyDbContext` that takes a `DbContextOptions<MigrationDbContext>` parameter; the child class can invoke this in *its* constructor. Also, `MigrationDbContext` will initially be confused that two projections are mapped to the same table; in its `SetupSomethingsWithProperty` method you should include a foreign key referencing the natural projection to clear up the confusion.

```
private static void SetupSomethingsWithProperty(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Something_WithProperty>(s =>
    {
        s.ToTable("Somethings");
        s.HasOne<Something>().WithOne().HasForeignKey<Something_WithProperty>(r => r.ID);
    });
}
```